# Qual a origem da expressão “Trabalhar que nem um galego”?

Tags: significado, expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica

Qual a origem da expressão “Trabalhar que nem um galego”? Surgiu onde?

Comment: CIMend, qual o significado da expressão? Se a expressão significar trabalhar muito, num sentido pejorativo, geralmente trabalho difícil ou chato ou repetitivo, mas não precisando pensar, assim como em "ô, trabalhinho de corno!", então, acho que "galego" não tenha importância; onde mora meu pai, o interruptor do banheiro é do lado de fora, e ele fala "coisa de português", o que se equivale a "coisa de filho da p*ta".

Comment: Aqui galego , refere- se a habitante da Galiza

Comment: https://digitalis-dsp.uc.pt/bitstream/10316.2/34512/1/Veredas16_artigo2.pdf?ln=pt-pt

Comment: É  uka boa resposta a colocar

Comment: @Schilive Não sei qual sentido seu pai dá quando fala isso, mas suponho que possa também querer dizer que foi um serviço mal-planejado, dado o histórico no Brasil de se pintar jocosamente os portugueses/colonizadores como cometedores de estultices, vide as tais "piadas de português".

Comment: Mas voltando ao assunto, dos galegos só sei que é recorrente em um ramo familiar meu (que inclui descendentes de espanhóis e portugueses) o xingamento "sarna galega" quando se perde a paciência com alguém.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Brasil, Galego é uma expressão nordestina, pois quando o Brasil foi colonizado, pessoas de Galicia vieram diretamente para o Brasil pelo nordeste, então eles costumavam chamar essas pessoas estrangeiras de Galegos e o termo costuma ser muito utilizado para descrever alguém com características europeias (loiro, pele clara e olhos claros).

Galegos erm conhecidos na época por fazerem os trabalhos menores e com menos valor, como todos os imigrantes e deslocados em muitos países.

Já em Portugal, quando eu visitei, fiz essa pergunta a um local de Lisboa e ele disse que é usado no sul de Portugal para designar uma pessoa pobre, sem instrução, fazendo um trabalho de baixa qualificação e oriunda do norte de Portugal. É parecida com aqueles termos horrendos pejorativos usados no sul do Brasil para se referir às pessoas do nordeste. O norte de Portugal fez parte de uma província romana chamada Gallaecia (de onde vem a atual Galícia, na Espanha, galego = nativo da Galícia). Essa região nunca foi ocupada pelos Mouros/Árabes, por isso é mais comum de se encontrar lá pessoas de pele mais clara, cabelos louros e olhos claros. Ironicamente, e talvez por isso, o termo "galego" é usado no Brasil sem nenhum teor depreciativo para designar justamente alguém louro e de pele clara, geralmente descendente de alemão, polonês, holandês, italiano, ucraniano...

Mas até onde eu sei, os galegos foram durante séculos a força matriz da cidade de Lisboa, também fazendo trabalhos menores. Sem eles, os habitantes de Lisboa não teriam água, já que os galegos eram a maioria dos abastecedores.

Algumas pessoas tendem a entender esse dizer como alguém que é trabalhador empenhado e responsável. Mas eu tomaria cuidado ao usar esse termo.

Comment: "trabalhar como un galego" acaba  sendo uma maneira de  dizer "trabalhar como um peão". Só que hoje em dia  é melhor evitar qualquer referência às "etnias.

Comment: Infelizmente, muito da Gallaecia foi ocupada pelos Mouros.  Foi libertada pelo [Vímara Peres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vímara_Peres), o primeiro Conde de Portugal, em 868.